# Converse of uniform convergence theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i(x)$.

Suppose that $f$ is continuous, and each $f_i$ is continuous. Does it follow that the series converges uniformly to $f$?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think answer is no but got no example in mind.

Comment: Let $f_n(x)=0$ for $x\notin[n,n+1]$, $f(n+1/2)=1$, and let $f_n$ be  linear where it hasn't yet  been defined.